# AutoLayout Button, Gradient and won't adjust to height

Tags: ios, swift

I want to adjust every button's height to the screen size. To do so I've created the following class, which also contains my previously created gradient and shadow path:

```
extension UIButton {

    func typeMain() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.07
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true

        self.addCharacterSpacing()
        self.tintColor = UIColor.white
        let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)
        let sndColor = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 178/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 5.0

        self.applyGradient(colours: [color, sndColor], locations: [0.0, 1.0])

        let shadowSize : CGFloat = 2.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 178/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -shadowSize / 2,
                                                   y: shadowSize,
                                                   width: self.frame.size.width + shadowSize,
                                                   height: self.frame.size.height + shadowSize))
        self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

**The button is being adjusted to the screen size, but both the gradient and shadow aren't.** How can I do so?

Btw. no height constraint in Storyboard set.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UIButton` and override `layoutSubviews` to set `layer.shadowPath`, this will make sure that your shadow bounds match the view bounds

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let shadowSize: CGFloat = 2.0
        let shadowRect = CGRect(x: -shadowSize / 2,
                                y: shadowSize,
                                width: self.bounds.width + shadowSize,
                                height: self.bounds.height + shadowSize)
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowRect).cgPath        
    }

}
```

**Suggestions**

1. Not to add `typeMain` method as an extension to UIButton, but to move it within the above class
2. Keep the `shadowPath` simply to match view bounds, instead you can set `shadowOffset`

Here is the final class

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.07
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true

        self.tintColor = UIColor.white

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 5.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 178/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1.0, height: 2.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }

    private func applyGradient(_ rect: CGRect, colors: NSArray, locations: NSArray) {
        guard
            let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
            let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors, locations: [0, 0.5])
        else {
            return
        }

        ctx.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: .zero, end: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0), options: [])
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let startColor = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        let endColor = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 178/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        self.applyGradient(rect, colors: [startColor, endColor], locations: [0.0, 1.0])
    }

}
```

Following is a test of 2 buttons, 1st is UIButton, 2nd is subclassed `CustomButton`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("UIButton", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16.0, bottom: 0, right: 16.0)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.typeMain()

        let subclassedButton = CustomButton()
        subclassedButton.setTitle("UIButton Subclassed", for: .normal)
        subclassedButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        subclassedButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16.0, bottom: 0, right: 16.0)
        self.view.addSubview(subclassedButton)

        let salGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: salGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: salGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true

        subclassedButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: salGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        subclassedButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
    }

}
```

That yields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting the shadow path here relative to the frame size, rather than your generated constraint for height.

You could remove the following:

```
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -shadowSize / 2,
                                                   y: shadowSize,
                                                   width: self.frame.size.width + shadowSize,
                                                   height: self.frame.size.height + shadowSize))
```

And the shadow should hug the button just fine. If you want the shadow to have this path you've laid out however, you need to set the width and height based on what you set your constraints to (i.e. UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.07).

If you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, constraints will no longer be generated relative to whatever CGRect frame you've passed to the object. They're generated based on anchors and content size (here your height is explicitly set by that anchor but your width will remain constrained by the button's content size). In other words, self.frame is irrelevant here.

If you set it like this, it will work:

```
self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width).isActive = true
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -shadowSize / 2,
                                       y: shadowSize,
                                       width: self.frame.width + shadowSize,
                                       height: height + shadowSize))
```

Does that help?